# How to pass current Element ID into Document Ready jquery from a C# foreach loop?

Tags: c#, jquery, function, foreach

So I have this foreach loop...

```
@foreach (Attachment attachment in Model)
{
<tr class="row@(index%2 == 0 ? "" : " even")">
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(attachment.AttachedFilename, "ViewAttachment", "Auction", new {docID = attachment.AttachmentId}, new {target = "_blank"})
        </td>
        <td>
                <a id="@attachment.AttachmentId" class="publishAttachment" name="public" style="float: right" tabindex="7">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/cross_circle.png")" />
           </a>
       </td>
 </tr>
 index++;
 }
```

And I have this jquery...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.publishAttachment').click().confirmationDialog({ message: "Are you sure you want to cancel ?", okButton: "I am sure", cancelButton: "No, I don't want to do this",
        onSuccess: function () {
            var obj = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(obj);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

So basically when I click on the link I will get a pop up dialog which has a message on it and yes or no buttons.  However I can't complete the task if I can't get the ID to be passed into the document ready.  I could easily do it if it was an onclick within the link, but that doesnt work with the widget that I am using, so how do I get the ID of the clicked element.
Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.publishAttachment').click(function(){
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel ?")
        if (answer){
            var obj = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(obj);
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: This does work, but unfortunately I cannot use this as I must use the widget as its a very large system and its for a client and we have to go by the specifications provided.  So I cannot use this, I would have if I didnt have a choice.  Thanks for this though

Comment: what kind of widget is it? means jquery ui dialog

Comment: Its a Confirmation overlay widget, I'm not sure which one we have used, but its been customised quite a lot, however its similar to this one http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly you do this to get clicked elements Id

```
onClick="reply_click(this.id);"
```

here you can enhance as

```
   if (yourConfirmMessageHere){
        var obj = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(obj);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I tried implementing this however it doesnt want to work with the confirmationDialog widget that I am using. I'll keep trying though

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have done it.  I'm not sure if its the best of ways to be doing it but it works which is all I care about right now.  I can sort it out at a later date if I need to.  This is what I did.  Firstly I gave the link an onclick event called "myfunc" which has the attachment ID value.  Then I created a function which returns the value then I call that value within the document ready, like this...

```
function myfunc(value){
    theGlobalName = value;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.publishAttachment').confirmationDialog({ message: "Are you sure you want to cancel ?", okButton: "I am sure", cancelButton: "No, I don't want to do this",
        onSuccess: function () {
            var obj = theGlobalName;
            alert (obj);
        }
    });

});
```

Like I said, it probably isnt the best of ways to be doing it but it works for now.